# How to use transition_states() to show the transition of superimposed plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

How to use transition_states() to show the transition of a superimposed plot?

```
    I wish to highlight particular data points from the data using the package of `gganimate`.
```

Here is my attempt with a very simple example. I created the 1st dataset and the plot with 2 data points only.

```
#create df
df1= data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(2,3))

#plot
p1<- ggplot(df1,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
```

then, I wish to highlight one data point (x=2,y-3) with different colour, so I created the 2nd dataset and superimposed on the 1st plot to show the difference.

```
df2= data.frame(x=2,y=3)
p1+ geom_point(data=df2,color="red")
```

It is possible to use the `transition_states()` to show the transition from df1 to df2?

```
p1+transition_states(geom_point(data=df2,color="red"))
Error in order(ind) : argument 1 is not a vector
```

any suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you could build one 'long' `data.frame` containing all the data and most importantly a column specifying the time or state. So the first step is to merge or bind `df1` and `df2` into one long dataframe `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1= data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(2,3), color = "black", time = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)
df2= data.frame(x=2,y=3, color = "red", time = 2, stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2)

> df
  x y color time
1 1 2 black    1
2 2 3 black    1
3 2 3   red    2
```

I also already added the color column. From here I create the animation:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) +
        geom_point(size = 10, show.legend = F) +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
        transition_states(time)
```

Since this is a rather 'static' animation one could also show the transition of the data more clearly by adding an additional step (`df3`):

```
df1= data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(2,3), color = "black", time = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)
df2= data.frame(x=2,y=3, color = "black", time = 2, stringsAsFactors = F)
df3= data.frame(x=2,y=3, color = "red", time = 3, stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) +
        geom_point(size = 10, show.legend = F) +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
        transition_states(time)
```

Since you wanted a superimposition of your plot, you could use the `shadow_mark` command:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) +
        geom_point(size = 10, show.legend = F) +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
        transition_states(time) +
        shadow_mark()
```

And there you have it, three different animations (note, that I added the titles in the gif):
[image]

[Here](https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html) are some additional [information](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate).